# How to convert a IEnumerable<DataColumn> into a Datatable?

Tags: linq, datatable

I got this:

```
var dsetValueFields = rds.Result.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Where(c=>c.DataType==typeof(Decimal));
```

And need to convert into a DataTable. Tried this:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.AddRange(dsetValueFields.ToArray());
```

But get error, "Column is part of another table."

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to create copies of the columns in your enumerable. Like `DataRow`s, `DataColumn`s can only be attached to one table.

```
dt.Columns.AddRange(dsetValueFields
                   .Select(c => new DataColumn(c.Name, c.DataType))
                   .ToArray());
```